# How to check if void* is IUnknown* at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows

How to check if void* is IUnknown* at runtime?

```
IUnknown *unk = dynamic_cast<IUnknown*>(item);
```

Does not work(compilation error).

Comment: Doesn't dynamic_cast use it?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?"  Can you elaborate on exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: RTTI will not work. IUnknown is a COM interface. You need to use the COM functions to test if you convert the value to an IUnknown. (And you probably have to catch system exceptions (using TRY and EXCEPT, not C++ exceptions using try and catch) for cases when the pointer is not an IUnknown.

Comment: Mark this as Windows if IUnknown is the standard Windows COM object interface and not something homegrown.

Comment: @Stan: Really, that would make it work... blindly changing the pointer type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot determine that definitively at runtime. You cannot take an arbitrary address and determine whether or not a real `IUnknown` lies behind it.

Comment: This was my guess. But I can't say it definitively. An IUnknown* isn't really a C++ object pointer. It's more like a vtable ptr to a non-C++ object.

Comment: Definitively. The observation you quote is in fact the reason why. A `void*` really is a C++ object pointer, which means you're dealing with different domains and you can't use functions from either domain to infer anything about the other side. BTW an `IUnknown*` is not a vtable pointer, but a pointer to a vtable pointer.